# Converting sql script to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (a nvarchar(max), b nvarchar(10), c nvarchar(100), d nvarchar(1000), e datetime, f int)
INSERT #tmp VALUES ('1', null, '2', null, GETDATE(), null)
```

and this SQL script that drops the null columns:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    #tmp

SELECT  name, CAST(0 AS BIT) checked
INTO    #col_names
FROM    tempdb.sys.columns 
WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp')

DELETE C
FROM    (   SELECT *
            FROM #tmp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS T(XMLCol)
        CROSS APPLY T.XMLCol.nodes('*') AS n(Col) 
        INNER JOIN #col_names C
            ON c.name = Col.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)')

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ', ' + QUOTENAME(name), QUOTENAME(name))
FROM    #col_names

SET     @sql = 'ALTER TABLE #tmp DROP COLUMN ' + @sql

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)

SELECT  * 
FROM    #tmp

DROP TABLE #tmp
DROP TABLE #col_names
```

which work perfectly fine. Now I tried to convert this to stored procedure and I getting error the syntax is not correct near SELECT???

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_DROP_NULL
@inputtable AS NVARCHAR(50)

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @sqlstr NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @LclTable NVARCHAR(50)

    SET @LclTable = @inputtable
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @LclTable

    SELECT  name, CAST(0 AS BIT) checked
    INTO    #col_names
    FROM    tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(@LclTable)

    SET @sqlstr = N'DELETE C
                    FROM ( SELECT * 
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS T(XMLCol)
                CROSS APPLY T.XMLCol.nodes(''*'') AS n(Col)
                INNER JOIN #col_names C
                    ON c.name = Col.value(''local-name(.)'',''VARCHAR(MAX)'')'


    SELECT  @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ', ' + QUOTENAME(name), QUOTENAME(name))
    FROM    #col_names

    SET     @sql = 'ALTER TABLE '+ @LclTable + ' DROP COLUMN ' + @sql

    PRINT '@sql is: ' + @sql
    EXEC (@sql)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @LclTable

    DROP TABLE @LclTable
    DROP TABLE #col_names

END
```

what have I done wrong? what I do i need to do to convert the above script to stored procedure?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the full error message. Also double click the error message and indicate what it failed on. When I ran this I  actually  got `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_DROP_NULL, Line 37 Incorrect syntax near '@LclTable'`, which makes sense because `DROP TABLE @LclTable` is not valid SQL. If you compare this to your original script it's different, as are a number of other things.

Comment: Here is the complete error message: (0 row(s) affected)
Msg 263, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Must specify table to select from.
@sql is: ALTER TABLE #tmp DROP COLUMN SELECT * FROM #tmp
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: OK we have a fair bit of confusion here. This message is now AFTER the change I indicated in my answer? Looks like you applied my suggested change to the wrong place. This is going to get very confusing.

Comment: I commented out the last two lines. those lines for garbage collection and do not really affect the functionality of script. this line:  "  @sql is: ALTER TABLE #tmp DROP COLUMN SELECT * FROM #tmp "    this the output of PRINT statement in the script and it's for debugging. shortly, before and after your suggestion the output error is the same.

Comment: I see whats happening now... for starters remove the line that says `SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @LclTable` or at least set it to `''` when you're finished with it. The next problem is that the temp table `#col_names` is empty for some reason. You also need to post the syntax you are using to call the stored procedure.

Comment: that's for debug purposes and doesn't change anything if I commented out. #col_names is not empty I can see the content in the PRINT statement. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the stored proc code

```
Create PROCEDURE SP_DROP_NULL
@inputtable AS NVARCHAR(50)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @sqlstr NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @LclTable NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Dropsql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @LclTable = @inputtable

exec ('SELECT * FROM ' + @LclTable)


SELECT  name, CAST(0 AS BIT) checked
INTO    #col_names
FROM    tempdb.sys.columns 
WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..'+@LclTable)

select * from #col_names

SET @sqlstr = N'DELETE C
                FROM ( SELECT *  from '+@inputtable +'
                FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE) AS T(XMLCol)
            CROSS APPLY T.XMLCol.nodes(''*'') AS n(Col)
            INNER JOIN #col_names C
                ON c.name = Col.value(''local-name(.)'',''VARCHAR(MAX)'')'


exec (@sqlstr)

select * from #col_names
SELECT  @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ', ' + QUOTENAME(name), QUOTENAME(name))
FROM    #col_names
SET     @sql = 'ALTER TABLE '+ @LclTable + ' DROP COLUMN ' + @sql
PRINT '@sql is: ' + @sql
EXEC (@sql)

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @LclTable

SET @Dropsql = 'DROP TABLE ' +  @LclTable 
EXEC (@Dropsql)

DROP TABLE #col_names

END
```

There are some issues while converting your script to sp

- You have not executed @sqlstr
- Not properly escaped all the characters in the @sqlstr
- @sql variable used before SET operation

Comment: Updated by answer with details

Comment: Thanks Mohank. your solution solved a couple of problems but one last thing is still hanging there. Now the error as far I can see in the log is relate to:    SET     @ sql = 'ALTER TABLE '+ @ LclTable + ' DROP COLUMN ' + @ sql
PRINT '@ sql is: ' + @ sql
....................................................................                                                                 EXEC (@ sql)    <--- IT DOES NOT LIKE THIS STATEMENT FOR SOME REASON

Comment: can you post your current query?

Comment: EXEC SP_DROP_NULL #tmp gives me error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','. I narrowed down the problem after several modification and testing to SELECT  @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ', ' + QUOTENAME(name), QUOTENAME(name)) FROM    #col_names    the ouput of working script is ALTER TABLE #tmp DROP COLUMN b, d, f     and not working scenario is ALTER TABLE #tmp DROP COLUMN , b, d, f    which if you notice is the , (i.e. the comma) before b column, so if i get this solved then the problem is solved.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I overlooked the fact I had DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '' when I removed the equal '' from the that line it worked. excellent job.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try changing

```
DROP TABLE @LclTable
```

to

```
SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE @LclTable'
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Those lines are just for garbage collection and I commented them out and still get the same error. The error is relate to these section: SELECT  name, CAST(0 AS BIT) checked
    INTO    #col_names
    FROM    tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID(@LclTable)

    SET @sqlstr = N'DELETE C
                    FROM ( SELECT * 
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS T(XMLCol)
                CROSS APPLY T.XMLCol.nodes(''*'') AS n(Col)
                INNER JOIN #col_names C
                    ON c.name = Col.value(''local-name(.)'',''VARCHAR(MAX)'')'

Comment: I am just trying to create stored procedure from the script. the error I am getting I think is from this part of script:       SELECT name, CAST(0 AS BIT) checked INTO #col_names FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@LclTable) SET @sqlstr = N'DELETE C FROM ( SELECT * FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS T(XMLCol) CROSS APPLY T.XMLCol.nodes(''*'') AS n(Col) INNER JOIN #col_names C ON c.name = Col.value(''local-name(.)'',''VARCHAR(MAX)'')'